# Escaping quotes in ckeditor breaks smarty-syntax

Tags: email, pdf, smarty

The ckeditor has the habit to escape characters like quotes or umlauts. This breaks the smarty-syntax when generating PDFs or mails.
Is there a good work-around or solution?

Answer (score 10):

Go to **Administer menu » Customize Data and Screens » Display Preferences**, click the **Configure CKEditor** button and add **entities** = **false** in the advanced options (see screenshot).[image]

**Note:** This is the default in CiviCRM 5.61+.

keywords: quotation marks, double quotes

Comment: Yes - you can do it in the Administer>>Customize Data and Screens>>Display Preferences>>Configure CKEditor button: solved the Smarty errors, but revealed something else, but I expect that is my error!

Comment: @MickKahn What did you change in the configuration to solve the smarty errors?

Comment: Hmm... can't now remember exactly what my issue was or what I did. I may just have been giving details of how you configure ckeditor in CiviCRM 4.7 onwards. It looks as if I only found a partial solution anyway. The only additional config I have is entities (Boolean) (whether to use HTML entities in the editor output) set to "false". Sorry to be vague.

Comment: This is much more important in Civi 5.43+ because of the use of quotation marks with the `crmDate` filter.

Answer (score 2):

A much simpler solution is to keep the portion of your smarty code that has quotes into HTML comments, so that the quotes won't be escaped:

```
<!-- {capture assign=genre}{contact.gender}{/capture}
{if $genre == "F"}{assign var='salutation' value='Chère'}
{else}
{assign var='salutation' value='Cher'}{/if} 
 --> 
<p>Chers parents, {$salutation} {contact.first_name},</p>
```

Comment: I am sorry: this doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking for how to do this in Configure CKEditor, the setting you need is /civicrm/admin/ckeditor and set entities = false under advanced options.

Comment: I have this configuration in CKEditor but with CiviCRM 5.65.2 and 5.67.1 (WordPress) the problem still exists: go to civicrm/admin/messageTemplates, edit a template and add some Smarty code with quote or double quotes. If you switch from and to "source code" you will see "&quot;"