# How to disable or fix the wysiwyg editor on civimail

Tags: civimail, wysiwyg

Oh joy of wysiwyg editors, that are going to alter the html you have so carefully typed to be compatible with all the mail clients in their glorious diversities...

For some mailings at least, I'd like to be able to tell the editor to stay home and let me type my html directly, as the W3C gods intended. Unfortunately, the setting to change the editor (CKEDITOR, tinyeditor or textarea) doesn't seem to be taken into account in civimail (or ab testing)

Is this a cache that I couldn't clear after the change (it worked fine for "normal" mail sendings, just civimail that ignored the new setting)?

Is there a bit of code to hack to make it work?

Comment: Did you manage to achieve what you wanted? Any of the answers helped you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Editing markup**

The editor includes a "Source" button which can be used to edit markup directly.

**Using `<textarea>`**

Upgrade to v4.7!

**In depth**

CiviCRM v4.6 includes a pure-JS rewrite of the CiviMail frontend. Unfortunately, the old WYSIWYG abstraction couldn't adapt well to pure-JS, so CiviMail in v4.6 only supports one editor. (Specifically, CiviMail uses the [`crmUiRichtext`](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/4.6/ang/crmUi.js#L394) directive which is hardcoded to CKEditor.) However, all other screens still use the old WYSIWYG abstraction.

v4.7 cleans things up by switching to a pure-JS WYSIWYG abstraction. The core ships with only two options (CKEditor and `<textarea>`). However, you can write an extension that defines alternatives (e.g. https://civicrm.org/extensions/tinymce ).

See also: https://civicrm.org/blogs/colemanw/big-changes-wysiwyg-editing-47

Comment: hey, the source button allows you to edit the source, but the editor is still going to alter what you typed after you save it

Answer (score 0):

I know that's not exactly what you requested, but you might consider disabling the character escaping behaviour of the editor altogether.

[Here is how.](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/7212/escaping-quotes-in-ckeditor-breaks-smarty-syntax)

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer the question neither but it might help.

What I do to prevent CKEditor from striping/modifying the markup is disable CKEditor's Advanced Content Filter (ACF), editing the config.js file in `/path/to/civicrm/packages/ckeditor`, more info [here](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_allowed_content_rules).

```
config.extraAllowedContent = 'html;head;body;span;ul;li;table;td;style;*[id];*(*);*{*}';

[ ] // for attributes

{ } // for styles

( ) // for classes
```

Comment: I can't get this to work. I have pasted the exact js into `packages/ckeditor/config.js` but that does not seem to affect the mailings editor. I'm on 4.7.

Comment: There's also the `bower_components/ckeditor/config.js`. When is that used?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that the CKeditor configurator at *Administer->Custom data and Views->Display* persists the editor configuration in a file in `/media/civicrm/persist/crm-ckeditor-config.js` and that file is overwritten each time you touch the configurator.

It looks like CiviCRM does this by replacing the reference to the default config.js (in `packages/ckeditor` with a reference to the persisted config. So any configuration placed here is simply never read.

So I can't see any solution to this problem until there is a way to insert custom config directives into that persisted config. (Except for re-adding it every time you re-configure CKEditor...).

Comment: your post doesn't answer the original question, you might want to ask a new question explaining your problem/issue. Regarding your note and previous comments, have a look at at Tim Otten's answer below and also read https://civicrm.org/blogs/colemanw/big-changes-wysiwyg-editing-47 in the comments of that post you'll find a tip on how you would load your own config.js file using __hook_coreResourceList__ in an extensions which seems to answer your questions

Comment: Thanks for that thin thread to follow. I've removed my frustrated ranting, As my answer now stands I think it helps readers to understand that beyond implementing their own Civi-extensions there is currently no way to do what the OP asks, right?

Comment: And FWIW, I think Tim Otten's answer is not explaining the situation very clearly. Perhaps you, @Andrei could supply a clearer answer based on your comment.

Comment: if you think Tim Otten's answer is not explanatory enough, perhaps you could suggest an edit so he can update it. Regarding you previous comment I guess the answer is No, I don't think is possible to disable CKEditor on a per component basis (CiviMail) without affecting the whole system, 'normal' emails, activities, etc... So you either go with CKEditor, Textarea or an Extension to implement another WYSWIG editor of your choice.

Comment: Maybe I was reading too much into the question... I found a very clear answer to the question I probably wanted to ask, which is consistent with your first comment, at http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/4526/354,

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem of the CKEditor config not 'taking' on a multisite / Aegir system and after much work solved this.

Our solution is detailed here: Is this a bug - [civicrm.files] variable