# PHP Fatal error: Smarty error: [in string: (...)]: syntax error: (secure mode) (...) not allowed in if statement (...)

Tags: wordpress, smarty, templates

The CiviCRM doumentation describes, how to use Smarty to customize templates for mails and pdf's:

https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/common-workflows/tokens-and-mail-merge/#smarty

E.g.:

```
{capture assign=gift}{contact.custom_16}{/capture}
{if $gift == Yes}
  This membership is a gift from {contact.custom_17}.
{/if}
```

Or:

```
{capture assign=Anredestil}{contact.communication_style}{/capture}
<br/>vielen Dank für 
{if $Anredestil eq 'Du'}Deine{else}Ihre{/if}
```

However, in certain conditions (especially but not limited to CiviCRM on Wordpress), this creates fatal errors like:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Smarty error: [in string:&lt;p&gt;{capture assign=Anredestil}Du{/capture}&lt;
br /&gt;vielen Dank f&amp;uuml;r {if $Anredestil eq &amp;quot;Du&amp;quot;}Deine{else}Ihre{/if} Spende.&lt;/p&gt; line 1]: syntax error: (secure mode) 'quot' not allowed in if statement (Smarty_Compiler.class.php, line 1399) in /html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/c
ivicrm/civicrm/packages/Smarty/Smarty.class.php on line 1100
```

An obvious solution might be, to deactived the "secure mode" - however, this might create an unsafe situation.

Answer (score 1):

After looking again I think this is ckeditor converting your smarty code to html. See also [Escaping quotes in ckeditor breaks smarty-syntax](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/7212/escaping-quotes-in-ckeditor-breaks-smarty-syntax)

Answer (score 0):

There is a surprisingly simple solution:

Smarty assumes, that comparison containing a constant string is unsafe.
A remedy is, to assign the constant value to a variable, and to perform the comparison between these two variables.

The code example from above could look like:

```
{capture assign=gift}{contact.custom_16}{/capture}
{capture assign=Yes}Yes{/capture}
{if $gift == $Yes}
  This membership is a gift from {contact.custom_17}.
{/if}
```

Good luck!

Comment: I think the docs might be wrong - the Yes is just missing quotes. You should be able to just do `{if $gift == 'Yes'}`

Comment: @demerit: No, this not the solution in the case I mentioned! 
(I just double-checkecd...)

Comment: Ok looking at your fatal error again it seems to be `<p>{capture assign=Anredestil}Du{/capture}<br />vielen Dank f&ur {if $Anredestil eq &"Du&"}Deine{else}Ihre{/if} Spende.</p>` - is there a reason you have `&` in there? Is that part of your original smarty code?

Comment: Oh I wonder if this is ckeditor converting your smarty code to html internally. That's come up before. See https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/7212/escaping-quotes-in-ckeditor-breaks-smarty-syntax