# Is Smarty processing also available for sending single mails which are not a part of a mass mailing?

Tags: civimail

I try to send a single mail through Contacts > New Mail using a template containing next Smarty instructions:

```
{if {contact.preferred_language} == "fr_FR"}OK{else}KO{/if}
```

but these mails cause an error with a very cryptic message:

> Error
>
> The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

EDIT: Thanks to Demerit (see below), I could identify what is working and what not. The smarty code

```
{capture assign=pref}{contact.preferred_language}{/capture}

{contact.email_greeting} ({contact.preferred_language} = {$pref}?),
```

is working as expected and gives the expected output

> Monsieur (fr_FR = fr_FR?),

So, the `{capture}`instruction is working, but when I add the instruction below

```
{if $pref == "fr_FR"}OK{/if}
```

I get the error message described above and no message is sent.

Comment: Do you mind to paste your smarty code? may be there should be some syntax error in your smarty?

Comment: @PradeepNayak: Sure, you are right: I should have done that before. I edited my question above to include the code causing the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for pasting the code: You can't use tokens inside a smarty command like that.

You need to do:

```
{capture assign=pref}{contact.preferred_language}{/capture}
{if $pref == "fr_FR"}OK{else}KO{/if}
```

Comment: Now getting "Mailing Error Expected a string or file resource" as error.

Comment: Where do I have to insert the `{capture ...}` instruction? Into the body of the HTML text, into the plain text, or into the subject field. I need the variable `$pref` from the three places.

Comment: There was als another problem: when I paste the smarty code into an HTML editor, the quotes are changed into entities `&quot;` that smarty doesn't recognise.

Comment: There is a setting https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/7212/escaping-quotes-in-ckeditor-breaks-smarty-syntax