# Smarty if instruction in message templates not working in single mails

Tags: civimail, smarty

I try to send single emails (Contacts > New Email) using a message template containing smarty conditional instructions in the html part of the message and in the text part of it.

HTML format:

```
<p>{capture assign=lang}{contact.preferred_language}{/capture}</p>

<p>{contact.email_greeting} ({$lang}),</p>

<p>{if $lang == 'fr_FR'}OK{/fi}</p>
```

Plain-Text Format

```
{capture assign=lang}{contact.preferred_language}{/capture}
{contact.email_greeting} ({$lang}),
{if $lang == 'fr_FR'}OK{/fi}
```

For avoiding problems with the quotes in the smarty instructions being changed into entities, I disabled the CKeditor and I am editing the HTML part of the message in a textarea.

The ´{capture}` instructions work as expected.

But whatever I try to do, every time I include the `{if}` instruction in the HTML part as in the plain text part, that part of the mail is not sent. If I remove the conditional instruction, the other instructions work.

I don't understand why this simple construction is not working.

Comment: how does this relate to your question  2 days ago https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/40200/is-smarty-processing-also-available-for-sending-single-mails-which-are-not-a-par

Comment: @petednz-fuzion: Some days ago, it worked once, but I couldn't reproduce this behaviour.

Comment: @petednz-fuzion: Thanks to Demerit, I see where I introduced a new error: it was a tipo: `{/fi}` instead of `{/if}`, and so muy problem is fixed again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

{/fi} isn't the right syntax to close the if, use {/if}

Comment: Gosh... How could I oversee that?