# Tokens containing HTML have the HTML escaped

Tags: tokens, html

I want to add the event description token to an event scheduled reminder. The event description is a rich text field.

When I add the token to the reminder and send it out, all the HTML from the token is escaped  rather than formatted.

Is there a solution to this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Escaping quotes in ckeditor breaks smarty-syntax](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/7212/escaping-quotes-in-ckeditor-breaks-smarty-syntax)